# ssrs expression to split string possible?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

so in my query i have `select columnx from tblz`

it returns `001.255556.84546`

I want to be able to split this via '.' and put it into three columns.

```
column1 = 001
column2 = 255556
column3 = 84576
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create three calculated fields with the following expressions:

```
=(Split(Fields!columnx.Value, ".")).GetValue(0)
=(Split(Fields!columnx.Value, ".")).GetValue(1)
=(Split(Fields!columnx.Value, ".")).GetValue(2)
```

I'm not sure it works or not, maybe give it a try.  You might need to use IIF() statement to check values before getting them.

Comment: This doesn't work. The answer that uses .GetValue(0) is the correct one.

Answer (score 13):

For info, in 2008 these dont work, you have to do the following:

```
=Split(Fields!returnedValue.Value, ".").GetValue(0)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. '.Value(0)' from the current accepted answer does not work.

Answer (score 4):

In SSRS you reference the field name, tell it the delimiter to use. Since you are not assigning to a variable, per se, you then need to tell it which part of the split string to use. In your example

```
=Split(Fields!returnedValue.Value,".")(0)
=Split(Fields!returnedValue.Value,".")(1)
=Split(Fields!returnedValue.Value,".")(2)
```

You would replace returnedValue with whatever the actual field name is, and place each one of those into your columns 1 - 3, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was originally posted in the question instead of being posted as an answer:

```
=(Split(Fields!columnx.Value,".")).GetValue(0)
=(Split(Fields!columnx.Value,".")).GetValue(1)
=(Split(Fields!columnx.Value,".")).GetValue(2)
```