# SSRS expression split string with changing quantities

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I've used the following article ([ssrs expression to split string possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928888/ssrs-expression-to-split-string-possible)) to allow me to take data from a SQL column in this format:

```
IMAGE01 IMAGE02 IMAGE03 (all these values are in one field)
```

and present it in my SSRS report split so it appears in the report cell as:

```
IMAGE01
IMAGE02
IMAGE03
```

The problem I am faced with is the quantity of `IMAGExx` values in my SQL cell is completely random, is there a way in SSRS of determining how many values there are in the split string to then split the correct amount out into rows like above?

Right now my expression is as such (for testing):

```
=(Split(Fields!something.Value, " ")).GetValue(0) & vbcrlf & (Split(Fields!something.Value, " ")).GetValue(2)
```

But I don't know if there are 2 values, or 9 values in the given field.

**EDIT**:

The below code is great, but gives me one extra new line inbetween values:

```
IMAGE01

IMAGE02

IMAGE03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use custom code to solve your problem.

Go to `Report` manu, `Report Properties` / `Code` Tab and put this code in the text area.

```
Public Function mySplit(ByVal my_field As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""       
    If my_field is Nothing or my_field = "" Then
        Return result
    End If
    Dim TestArray() As String = my_field.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    Dim word as String      
    For Each word In TestArray
        result = result + word + vbCrLf 
    Next
    Return result

End Function
```

Once your function is added to the report you can call it from expressions

```
=Code.mySplit(Fields!myField.Value)
```

It will split the values based on single spaces (" ") and return the values separated by new line `vbCrLf`.

Example:

```
=Code.mySplit("This is a test")
```

It returns:

```
This
is
a
test
```

**UPDATE:** Function will not return extra new line.

```
Public Function mySplit(ByVal my_field As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""       
    If my_field is Nothing or my_field = "" Then
        Return result
    End If
    Dim TestArray() As String = my_field.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    Dim word as String
    Dim counter as Integer = 0      
    For Each word In TestArray
        counter = counter +1
        If counter = TestArray.Length Then
            result = result + word
        Else
                result = result + word + vbCrLf 
        End if
    Next
    Return result

End Function
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: This looks fantastic, will try now!

Comment: This seems to give me rogue extra new lines on the split. See my edit

Comment: @PnP, It seems the words in your field are separated by double spaces. Check the spaces between words

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, it also generates a new line at the end, any way we can remove the trailing new line?

Comment: I also have some files in the table, with a name like "IMAGE SYS01". This now is also being split, can I avoid this with an if statement, like If it contains "SYS" do not split?

Comment: @PnP , I suggest you replace "E S" for "E_S" in your query, then in SSRS replace the "_" for " ".

Comment: I can't change what's in the SQL table, as the IMAGE files are pulled from file names in a folder/

Comment: I think there is a way to achieve that. `=REPLACE(Code.mySplit(REPLACE("IMAGE01 IMAGE02 IMAGE03 IMAGE SYS01","E S","E_S")),"_"," ")` It will work if your field keeps the IMAG**E**<space>**S**YSXX pattern. If you need more details create another question with this new issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181186/srss-expression-to-split-strings-excluding-specific-string