# SRSS Expression to split strings excluding specific string

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have the following function (answered by someone on this forum in another question):

```
Public Function mySplit(ByVal my_field As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""       
    If my_field is Nothing or my_field = "" Then
        Return result
    End If
    Dim TestArray() As String = my_field.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    Dim word as String
    Dim counter as Integer = 0      
    For Each word In TestArray
        counter = counter +1
        If counter = TestArray.Length Then
            result = result + word
        Else
                result = result + word + vbCrLf 
        End if
    Next
    Return result

End Function
```

This works to take a collection of words:

`"IMAGE01 IMAGE02 IMAGE03"` and display them in a report as:

```
IMAGE01
IMAGE02
IMAGE03
```

However, I have some images named `"IMAGESYS RES01"` which because of the above function are being split onto two lines:

```
IMAGESYS
RES01
```

I need to avoid this, as the above `"IMAGESYS RES01"` is just one file.

Comment: is The two-words values always `IMAGESYS RESXX`? Try indentifying a common pattern in the filenames.

Comment: Yes, it should always be "IMAGESYS RESxx" at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it always follows the pattern `IMAGESYS RESXX` this expression should work:

```
=REPLACE(Code.mySplit(REPLACE(Fields!YourField.Value,"S R","S_R")),"_"," ")
```

With this example `IMAGE01 IMAGE02 IMAGE03 IMAGESYS RES01 IMAGESYS RES02` it should return:

```
IMAGE01
IMAGE02
IMAGE03
IMAGESYS RES01
IMAGESYS RES02
```

**UPDATE** Explanation about how it is working:

The split does nothing different, the change is in the way we pass the values to the `mySplit` function. The `REPLACE(Fields!YourField.Value,"S R","S_R")` turns your field in this and pass it to the `mySplit` function:

```
IMAGE01 IMAGE02 IMAGE03 IMAGESYS_RES01 IMAGESYS_RES02
```

The `mySplit` function will return the below string based on the above passed argument.

```
IMAGE01
IMAGE02
IMAGE03
IMAGESYS_RES01
IMAGESYS_RES02
```

Once the function returns the above string the outer `REPLACE` function replace the `_` for `" "` (whitespace), leaving the string as:

```
IMAGE01
IMAGE02
IMAGE03
IMAGESYS RES01
IMAGESYS RES02
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks, works well. How exactly is that working with the split?

Comment: @PnP, check my update. Hope it helps you. Let me know if you don't understand anything in my brief explanation.