# Separating data from a column with multiple char(13) line breaks into their own columns

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

The field is called fmstreet when the field displays in SSRS it contains the managers name beginning with **ATTN: Store Manger, street address 1, and street address 2**,. The way the data looks in SSMS is ATTN: Brian Adams 343 Albert Ave 17th Street. This displays the field in SSRS

> ATTN: Brian Adams
>   343 Albert Ave
>   17th Street

I've been able to get the first line into it's own column but don't know exactly how to do the other two. Also some rows only have one street address not two.

```
SELECT somast.fsono, 
somast.fcustno,
somast.fcontact,
soship.fmstreet,
Case When cast(soship.fmstreet AS CHAR(100)) like 'ATTN:%'
Then LEFT(cast(soship.fmstreet AS CHAR(100)),CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),cast(soship.fmstreet AS CHAR(100))))
End as 'Attention'
FROM  soitem
INNER JOIN somast ON soitem.fsono = somast.fsono
LEFT OUTER JOIN oship ON somast.fsono = soship.fcsono AND soship.fcenumber = ''
WHERE  (somast.fstatus <> 'Cancelled') AND (somast.fsocoord = 'IFP'
OR somast.fsocoord = '711');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option here is to look into using the Split function in SSRS and you can split the string based on char(13), I think.  This post seems like it would direct you correctly, I would definitely check for the value's existance like it suggests.

[ssrs expression to split string possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928888/ssrs-expression-to-split-string-possible)

Comment: Thank you for the link ,I'll give it a look and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are doing results to grid... change your SSMS output to results to text and you'll see the line breaks. Tools > Options > Query Results > Results To Text or just click the button on the tool bar,it's the one on the left in the image below:

[image]

Comment: This isn't I'm asking to do.